# .NET Core MVC:Как с помощью Url.Action() отправить сложный объект (объект в объекте)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Я хочу отправить модель с данными на сервер.

Для быстрой сортировки, я использую `<a>` и `Url.Action()`, с помощью которого я отправляю сортировочную модель данных.

Когда я кликаю на ссылку, в адресную строку выводиться следующее:
"...&FilterData=**Project.Web.Models.FilterData**" за место полей, этого объекта...

```
localhost/User?PageNum=1&SortOrder=NameAsc&FilterData=Project.Web.Models.FilterData
```

Html

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "User", new FilterRequest(filter, sort, pagination))"> First Name </a>
```

Мой код:

**FilterRequest.cs**

```
public class FilterRequest
{
     public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;

     public SortType SortOrder { get; set; } = SortType.None;

     public FilterData FilterData { get; set; }
}
```

**FilterData.cs**

```
public class FilterData
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string MiddleName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно, `FilterData` поле является объектом, и я не могу понять почему он не отображает его?

Код контроллера:

**UserController.cs**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(FilterRequest request)
    {

    }
}
```

Как отправить данные вложенного объекта?

Comment: А это точно весь код? Как вы создаёте новый объект таким образом, если в классе нет конструктора? `new FilterRequest(filter, sort, pagination)`  Хотелось бы увидеть всё же все значимые элементы этих классов. Хотя бы конструкторы и `ToString` если есть. И аттрибуты, если есть.

Comment: Это особо не имеет значения.. суть в том, что если отправить с помощью `@Url.Action(,, new Model())` И в model будет вложенный объект... Helper Url отобразит имя объекта, а не его содержание..

Comment: Используйте POST запросы для такого.

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к мнению, что POST для таких случаев будет лучше. / [Тыц](https://forums.asp.net/t/2017595.aspx?How+to+pass+object+of+class+in+url+action+in+mvc+C+) - нужно либо в плоскую модель преобразовать ваш сложный класс, либо в json. Принимающую сторону изменить соответственно.